# SSRS Calculated Fields ends up showing error

Tags: reporting-services, calculated-field, ssrs-2016

In SSRS reports I have created this calculated fields to calculate or return sales of Bike WRT to the previous year but it ends up showing error:-

The expression used for the calculated field **'CompareSales'** includes an *Aggregate, RowNumber, Running Value, Previous or lookup* function. 
*Aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous and lookup* functions cannot be used in calculated field expressions.

I have tried every possibility to avoid error.

This is my piece of code:

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!Year_1.Value=MAX(Fields!Year_1.Value),Fields!BikeBuyer.Value,0))
-SUM(iif(Fields!Year_1.Value=MAX(Fields!Year_1.Value)-1,Fields!BikeBuyer.Value,0))
/SUM(iif(Fields!Year_1.Value=MAX(Fields!Year_1.Value)-1,Fields!BikeBuyer.Value,0))
```

When I remove SUM() from my code it executes successfully, but it won't produce the proper output.

Please Suggest me what I can do!!!

Thank You in Advance

Comment: An alternative is to do the aggregates/running values etc in SQL as extra columns and use the SQL values rather than rely on SSRS.

Comment: Thanks for that alternative suggestions. But I also tried this alternative but end up showing warning that "Can't aggregate date Vale with numeric value!!!!"